# Reversing the positions of words in a string without changing order of special characters in O(1) space limit

Tags: c++, arrays, string, reverse

During mock interview I come up with this question. Interviewer first ask  this question without any space limitations. Then he continued with space-limited version. To be on the same page. In the question a string and container class consist of delimiters are given. This is up to you to decide suitable container class  and the language of response. I think sample input and output would be enough to understand what really question is.

Input:

```
"Reverse#Strings Without%Changing-Delimiters"
```

Output:

```
"Delimiters#Changing Without%Strings-Reverse"
```

Note That: Position of **"#", "%","  ","-"** is not changed

I came up with the solution below:

```
string ChangeOrderWithoutSpecial(string s, unordered_set<char> delimiter)
{
    stack<string> words; // since last words outs first
    queue<char> limiter; // since first delimiter outs first
    string response =""; //return value
    int index=-1; // index of last delimiter visited
    int len=s.length();
    for (int i =0 ; i <len;i++)
    {
        if(delimiter.find(s[i]) != delimiter.end()) // i-th char is a delimiter character
        {
            string temp=s.substr(index+1,i-index-1);
            words.push(temp);
            char t =s.at(i);
            limiter.push(t);
            index=i;
        }
    // i realized that part after interview under assumption starting with word and no double delimiters ie, each word followed by one delimiter
    if(index!=s.length()-1)
    {
        string temp=s.substr(index+1,s.length()-index-1);//until the end;
        cout<<temp<<endl;
        words.push(temp);
    }
    while(!limiter.empty())
    {
        response+=words.top()+limiter.front();

        words.pop();
        limiter.pop();
    }
    response+=words.top();
    return response;  

}
```

However I couldnt find a o(1) space solution ? Anyone know how ? I also could not figure out if there are multiple delimiters , that also be appricated. Thank you anyone spend time even reading.

Comment: @JosephSible Actually I did attempted a lot but. My solution is not solves the O(1) space problem.

Comment: Reversing the word order is easily *the* most famous and overused interview question. The added requirement of leaving the delimiters order unchanged is nearly trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Find the first word and the last word. Rotate the string by `length(last_word)-length(first_word)`: this would put the middle part in the correct position. In the example, that'll produce

```
ersReverse#Strings Without%Changing-Delimit
```

Then rotate the first and last part of the string, skipping the middle, by `length(first_word)`:

```
Delimiters#Strings Without%Changing-Reverse
```

Repeat this algorithm for the substring between the two outermost delimiters.

"Rotate by `m`" operation can be performed in `O(1)` space and `O(n)` time, where `n` is the length of the sequence being rotated.

Comment: Rotate by m can be done in O(n) instead of O(n*m), see Juggling algorithm.

Comment: @Dejan Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rotating the string, it can be also solved by successive reversing the string.

- *Reverse the whole string.* This is `O(n)` operation. In your case the string becomes `sretimileD-gnignahC%tuohtiW sgnirtS#esreveR`.
- *Find all words and reverse each of them*. This is `O(n)` operation. String is now equal to `Delimiters-Changing%Without Strings#Reverse`.
- *Reverse delimiters*. This is `O(n)` operation. You'll get wanted result: `Delimiters#Changing Without%Strings-Reverse`.

Each of these operations can be done in place, so the total memory complexity is `O(1)` and time complexity is `O(n)`.

It is worth noting that with this approach each character will be visited 4 times (first reverse, finding words, reverse word, reverse delimiter), so (in general case) it should be faster than Igor Tandetnik's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52022113/1765621) where characters in the middle of the string are visited many times. However, in special case where each word has the same length, Igor's solution will be faster because the first rotate operation won't exists.

**Edit:**

*Reverse delimiters* can be done in `O(n)` without extra memory in the similar way as the standard reverse. Just iterate through delimiters instead of whole set of characters:

1. Iterate forward until you reach delimiter;
2. Reverse iterate until you reach delimiter from the back;
3. Swap the current delimiters;
4. Continue procedure until your iterators meet.

Here is procedure in `C++` which will do this job

```
void reverseDelimiters(string& s, unordered_set<char>& delimiters)
{
    auto i = s.begin(); auto j = s.end() - 1; auto dend = delimiters.end();
    while (i < j) {
        while (i < j && delimiters.find(*i) == dend) i++;
        while (i < j && delimiters.find(*j) == dend) j--;
        if (i < j) swap(*i, *j), i++, j--;      
    }
}
```

Comment: The above question ultimately boils down to reversing delimiter with using extra space, which you haven't given the solution. @Igor's has approached for that which is it think O(n*m) time solution.
Since you are claiming `Reverse delimiters` will take `O(n)` time + in place, so I would like to know an algorithm for that. Thanks!

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay I'm not sure what confuse you about `reverse delimiter` operation, but I edited the answer and put the code snippet. For me it was straight forward so I omitted it in the original answer.

Comment: bro, the algorithm you wrote is taking extra space, clearly, you are using `unordered_set<char>` which will cost you `O(m)` space complexity where `m` is the number of delimiters. Even the time complexity of your algorithm is not `O(n)`. @Igor's solution is the only solution which looks right to me.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay I'm not using extra space, unordered_set is the input to the algorithm (take a look at the question). The above procedure visits each char exactly once, and asks if it exists in the set (which is O(1) operation), so the total complexity is O(n).